# Limit evaluation using algebra of sequences and sequence theorems

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

By making use of only the theorems on sequences
(ex: algebra of sequences/cauchy's first theorem of sequences/limit of geometric mean of a sequence etc),
how to prove the following:
$lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$

Comment: This is a duplicate, but since I'm at my phone I can't look it up. Also does it question mean that the limit exists or that the limit exists and is e for some definition of e?

Comment: The question requires to show that the value of the limit is 'e'.

Comment: What is the definition of 'e'?

Answer (score 0):

$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e^{n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)}$$

Now 
$$n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \sim n \times \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 1$$

Comment: Can you elaborate the second expression where the limit of logarithm expression reduced to 1/n?

Comment: The symbol $\sim$ means "equivalent". Do you know what it is ?

Comment: If you don't know, here is another way to write it : consider the function $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$. You can see that $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} =\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1)}{x-0}$, so $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}= f'(0)= \frac{1}{1+0} = 1$. In particular, when $n \rightarrow +\infty$, $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{1/n} = 1$. In other terms, the limit of $n \ln(1 + 1/n)$ is indeed $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and it's clear! I knew the symbol. But i was not trying not to apply any of the concepts other than those related to sequences and few basics.

Comment: Yes I understand. But since your question involves the number $e$, it's natural to use concepts relative to exponential or logarithms...

Comment: Using properties of logaritms/exponential is completely fine. Can you please comment on how those terms are equivalent?

Comment: It is what is explained in my second comment here :) Equivalently, it's classical that $\ln(1+x)=x + o(x)$ near $0$. So that $\ln(1+x)/x \rightarrow 1$ when $x \rightarrow 0$. Replacing $x$ by $1/n$ in this limit gives you the equivalent you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply expand it using binomial theorem cancel out the n's and put n= infinity now all the terms that will be remaining will contain expression like (1-1/n)  and so on the term 1/n becomes zero as 1/infinity is zero. Now the resulting expression is the expansion of 'e' thus you get it as e

Comment: It is clear. But since Maclaurin series is required to conclude the last expression to 'e', can we do it in an alternative way?

Comment: I just suggested a way . There are many alternate ways to prove it.